# MSc for experienced professional?

Tags: career-path, masters, abroad

I have 8 years of IT experience in India, I want to do a Master of Science in the US. 
Would my already long professional experience hurt my chances to find a job after the MSc? I intend to settle in the US instead of coming back to India.

Answer (score 5):

I would expect that it almost certainly does not hurt your chances. Many people proceed their academic education or career after professional experience. In [our Master programme](http://www.spacemaster.eu), this is treated as a significant plus, and I would be very surprised if companies wouldn't do the same.

But for the non-academic portion of the question (I infer you mean a job outside academia), you might want to ask at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and get opinions there.

Answer (score 0):

You will be a very strong candidate in US provided you go to at least a reputable public university.

Comment: Hello, hoo, and welcome to Academia Stack Exchange. Your answer is in need of some improvement. Please try to include some more details in your answer so that it will be of benefit to other users.